# How to better store arrays of data for use in a JavaScript app

Tags: php, javascript

I have an interactive JavaScript app that runs through arrays of data. I don't want users to be able to easily view the array content, so I have stored the arrays in PHP and pass them to the JavaScript app with AJAX and JSON. I had thought about using a database, but since these files only have to read (not written) I thought it would be unnecessary.

Am I missing an obvious and easier way to do this? Perhaps some sort of server-side cache?

Cheers,

Comment: a database is excellent for read write or anything in between. especially if its large set of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't be using PHP to emit JSON arrays when you could just create static JSON files (like data.json) with the data already in JSON format.

Comment: Can the JSON data be viewed from a browser?

Comment: You would use the same javascript application using the same AJAX requests to read the static json files instead of reading dynamic php-created json files.

Comment: Cheers James, I really appreciate it.